# always returns 0 in onActivityResult Facebook in android

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk, onactivityresult

I have used login with Facebook in my app. until now I was using webView to let user login using Facebook. But as per new rules from Facebook we have to use app if its installed on user's device.

I completed development of my app and now i found out this. I was going to submit to play store. But due to this i think i won't be able to.

```
public void loginWithFacebook()
{

            Log.d(TAG, "Logging into Facebook.");

    String applicationId = Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(activity
            .getBaseContext());
    mCurrentSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (mCurrentSession == null || mCurrentSession.getState().isClosed())
    {
        Session session = new Session.Builder(activity.getBaseContext())
                .setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
    }
    mCurrentSession = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (!mCurrentSession.isOpened())
    {
        Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
        openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(activity);
        if (openRequest != null)
        {
            openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);

                openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_birthday",
                        "email", "user_hometown"));
                openRequest
                        .setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
                mCurrentSession.openForRead(openRequest);


        }
    }
}
```

So I changed LoginBehavior to "**SSO_WITH_FALLBACK**", now it'd displaying app if user has installed app. But my problem is that after login into app when it comes to "**onActivityResult**" i am always getting **resultCode** "**0**"

Comment: Have you added this to your manifest?     <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_facebook_login" >
      </activity>